# django default page when debug=True

Tags: django, url

Is there any way to redirect all unmatched urls to a certain view in django? I can't use 404 page normally, as i have `Debug = True`. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Add a url with regex that will catch anything at the end of your other urls?

Comment: @yuvi: That doesn't work either. I tried it. But that overrides some other urls too..

Comment: @yuvi: can u give me the regex for it? I think i got something wrong there. It doesn't work if the url contains `\`. Any idea on that?

Comment: I think `url('^.*',` but I'm looking in other directions now, for a less-hacky cleaner way to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of a hack, but it's simple enough - add a url that will match anything at the end of your other urls

```
    url(r'^.*', 'myapp.my_custom_errorview'),
```

Remembre that yiou have to **put it last**, else it will override all other urls.

Comment: I used the solution you suggested at the comments and that worked

Comment: My django-admin css is missing. any idea of why?

Comment: Added another possible option. Also, I just tested it - there's no problem with the hack. You just have to make sure that the catch-all url appears *after* the line `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),`. admin css is working fine for me with that setup

Comment: I took out the other stuff. I tested it, and it isn't working