# Django weird url call error

Tags: django, url

I have my Django app. I have a redirect URL(say a 404 page) to be redirected when no other URL matches. Now if any url is called as

```
mysite.com/something
```

I am redirected to the 404 page. But

```
mysite/something/
```

works fine.

The redirection url added to the end of all:

```
url(r'^.*/',theview),
```

When I remove the redirect url from the urls.py, the problem is cleared and the above URL works (without / at the end). Why is the error?

Comment: What does your urls.py look like exactly?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it would be a good idea to link to [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363182/django-default-page-when-debug-true/21363406?noredirect=1#comment32213384_21363406) and mention you are using a hack that I gave you, because (A) it's not normal setup and (B) Someone might come up with a better idea than mine

Secondly, you're seeing this behaviour because of normal url processing. See, the urls `mysite.com/something` and `mysite.com/something/` are **not** the same. To match it with django's urls, the difference would be:

```
url(r'^something/$')
url(r'^something$')
```

Since the difference is so minor, when using a normal setup, after failing to find the a url without a forward slash [django's common middlewere](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.common)* will automatically try to add one and test it. It's only then that it would give up and forward you to a 404 page.

However, in your setup, the catch-all url prevents the second round because it does apply to the url without the forward slash. My solution? Don't worry about it. The only reason you're using this hack is because `Debug=True` means a debug page instead of your custom 404 page, a problem you won't be facing when moving to a production environment

*and a big thanks to @Alasdair who pointed this out in the comments

Comment: It's not the browser that adds the slash it's the [Django common middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.common)

Comment: Now if I change all `something/$` to `something$`, will that work?

Comment: @Alasdair: Is there a way I can make the app to append the slash before checking with the urls?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh Yes, using `something$` will work. You can also create a regex to accept either a forward slash or nothing, but that's a lot of work that you don't need to do. Just remember to use the exactly-correct urls for your development and later, when moving to production, just remove the hack and use a proper 404

Comment: @AswinMurugesh the Django common middleware only appends the slash if the URL is not found in the URL conf. You will have to write your own middleware if you want to append a slash before checking the URL conf. I think that doing so would cause you other problems, and would be the wrong approach. Why not just set `debug=False`, and remove the catch all URL pattern? You shouldn't run with `debug=True` in production anyway.